# Network icon gone missing in wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel, luna

Wireless network icon suddenly missing from wingpanel. Cannot find option in `dconf-editor` to enable network icon.

I tried

```
killall wingpanel
```

but there was no change.

How can I get the network icon back in wingpanel?

Comment: Can you check whether you have `indicator-applet` installed?

Comment: Have you run updates and restarted your computer? Oftentimes that will solve issues like this. :)

Comment: I do have `indicator applet` installed, and I've tried updating fully and restarting. Still nothing.

Comment: I'd suggest to create new user, log under him, and check if the indicator is present. If it is present - you'll know it's a matter of your user's config. If it's missing - you'll know it's something global (something with the package probably?). Try it out and let us know the results - we'll then consider directions

Comment: Tried making another account. Once logged in, the network icon was not there. Something's gone amiss with the package.

Comment: Perhaps take a look here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/159812/network-manager-indicator-missing

Comment: @Gabriel not really a solution to reinstall a package... How about we identify where network manager applet is normally started and ask @svh160 to check it? ;)

@svh160 can you please try to start it manually? command would be `nm-applet`. I wonder if binary is in place. Also run command `dpkg -V network-manager-gnome` to verify package state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix was to reinstall `libappindicator` and reboot.

Here's the link to the answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/586319/203856

Answer (score 4):

Since the problem persists even on another new account it doesn't like it's a problem with an auto-start or visibility, it's something global, which I would bet on a package corruption...

I wrote a general troubleshooting post, just in case anyone else stumbles upon it with a slightly different problem. However, please follow all the steps to make sure. if it doesn't help - post us with results from each step.

---

First of all, lets check if nm-applet is in place in your system and it can be actually launched.

1. check if nm-applet is in-place:

   ```
   # ps aux | grep nm-applet
   ```

   if it's in place it's only a problem of visibility, check step 4. If it's missing - check step 2.
2. check binary and package presence:

   ```
   # ls -la `which nm-applet`
   # dpkg -V network-manager-gnome
   ```

   If it's missing or any problems with package - reinstall `network-manager-gnome` package. If everything is ok - move on to the next step.
3. If everything is in place - try to start it manually by running following command:

   ```
   # nm-applet
   ```

   If it keeps running and does not exit, and icon appears - it means its an auto startup problem. go to step 5

   If it keeps running without icon appearing - move on to the next step.

   If it exits right away - troubleshoot the exit errors. You can even try to strace as binary doesn't have many debug options:

   ```
   # strace -vtfs1024 -o /tmp/nm-applet-startup.strace.log nm-applet
   ```
4. If you've reached this place - it means your nm-applet can start just fine but you don't see the icon. probably issue is the visibility. Check it by calling gsettings:

   ```
   # gsettings get org.gnome.nm-applet show-applet
   ```

   if it returns false - bingo. That's the problem. Now call gsettings again to enable its visibility:

   ```
   # gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet show-applet true
   ```
5. If you've reached this place it probably means your nm-applet works fine but does not start automatically. we can fix that

   Open settings, locate Applications and Startup. Add "nm-applet" over there. I know in luna it can be different a bit but you've got to figure it out, I don't have Luna :) Should look somehow like on a screenshot below

   [image: nm-applet autostart manual configuration]

Comment: The `nm-applet` process is present. Once in step 4, however, I try `# gsettings get org.gnome.nm-applet show-applet` and get:

`No such schema 'org.gnome.nm-applet'`

Comment: @svh160 it could be because of the difference in Luna/Freya. Try "gsettings list-recursively | grep nm-applet | grep show", hope it helps

Comment: Output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep nm-applet` is blank. Output of simply starting `nm-applet` is : `** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon`

Comment: try launching it with # nm-applet --shell-debug

Comment: Output of `# nm-applet --shell-debug`: `** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

** (nm-applet:32634): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) No session found for uid 0
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
** Message: Starting applet secret agent because GNOME Shell disappeared`

Comment: Seems like you're running it under "root" user - it cannot find the X server session for root. Try with your current user

Comment: I've got 2 links for you, you may find them useful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192219 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/506824/nm-applet-does-not-work-ubuntu-14-04 - it seems like a rather common issue. Check suggestions. I suspect you have "Hidden=true" set for the applet

Comment: The first link provided the solution. "Hidden" was set to true already. The fix was to reinstall libappindicator1, and then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly same issue on Elementary OS Freya. This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet
sudo apt-get install indicator-application
```

Originally found on [google+ forum](https://plus.google.com/105328164957068530844/posts/PoQrNHjujQo)