# Network icon missing in Freya wingpanel

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, networking, icons

I have tried everything in [this thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/288/5565) and I have asked [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/3ndb7u/network_icon_missing_from_the_wingpanel/) but I am unable to get the network icon back. Please help.

Comment: How did you lose it in the first place? We would need more context to diagnose what happened to figure out how to get it back

Answer (score 1):

A [Google+ thread](https://plus.google.com/105328164957068530844/posts/PoQrNHjujQo) suggested:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet
sudo apt-get install indicator-application
```