# WiFi icon on wing panel disappeared

Tags: wingpanel, wifi, networking

Since WiFi icon disappear on wingpanel I'm unable to connect to the new WiFi networks. the connect button on the Network settings also not working, can anyone tell me how to fix the network icon or are there any way to connect to new WiFi networks?
[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after re-installing the network manager

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Read more : https://askubuntu.com/questions/577588/wifi-icon-is-not-displayed

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when the appindicator library fails to load.

Try restarting the wingpanel by `killall wingpanel`

If that doesn't work, try checking if you have `indicator-applet` & `indicator-application` installed or not.

If you already have them installed, try reinstalling `libappindicator` and then log out an back in.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libappindicator3-1 libappindicator1
```

For detailed reading: [Network icon gone missing](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/288/network-icon-gone-missing-in-wingpanel) & [nm-applet does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506824/nm-applet-does-not-work-ubuntu-14-04/586319#586319)

You should also check this: [Bug: No WIFI Icon Up In The Right Corner](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1161972)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but already tried these things and didn't work, is it possible to connect to the wifi using network settings ?

Comment: Yes it is possible to connect to wifi through network settings. The screenshot you provided shows you already know how to do that. The problem may be with your wifi drivers. Read this question and answer, it will help you detect whether your wifi device and drivers are ok. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/unable-to-connect-to-own-wifi-network-freya