# Wifi doesn't work

Tags: wifi, drivers

Since I have installed the os there is no possibility to connect using the WiFi. 
I am still able to connect to Internet using the USB thetering of my phone.

Would you please advice on how to get back online using WiFi?

Comment: Please update your question with your PC model and components. Also, what happens if you go inside System Settings > Networks, does it show a wifi option? Can you enable that option?

Comment: I experienced that issue: wifi icons and option desappear.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing a driver.  I had a similar problem and was fixed when I ran updates after install.  If not you need to find you wifi card and download the driver for it.  What are the specs for your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some drivers or packages missing. This worked for me: [WiFi icon on wing panel disappeared](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/wifi-icon-on-wing-panel-disappeared). Try it. I face such an issue many times (mainly after huge updates) and, until it is fixed, we will experience that problem.